# Creating a viewmodel in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I don't know how to write a viewmodel class for below combobox.

Suppose I have two tables namely: `Cars` and `EngineMakers`

Cars Table:

```
CarID
CarName
EngineMakerID (Foreign Key)
```

EngineMakers Table:

```
EngineMakerID
EngineMakerName
```

Now in combobox I want to show the `name of the EngineMaker` in the list. Now when I save changes `EngineMakerID in Cars` table should be updated. How to write viewmodel for the above Question?

Comment: First, do you have you `Model` layer? The `ViewModel` is basically a way to connect the `Model` with the `View`. When I sai basically, I mean really basic :)

Comment: I have my model and I also have combobox in my view. I have a very basic idea of viewmodel. But I don't know how to code for viewmodels. Yes I have searched the net about writing viewmodels but I don't understand there any thing. If someone explains me viewmodels by keeping in mind the above example or similar then it will be very much clear to me.

Comment: I understand, I'm beginning as well and this one thing I still struggle. The idea is create some sort of BLLesque class. I assume you implemented the `OnPropertyChanged()` in your `View`. What **I** would do is check whether I have or not an object from the Class inside the constructor. It's a detailed thing, I'll give you some links, sorry.  www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/ (good lightweight ToolKit); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx (Some example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you basically want to have car table that refernces the engine maker model

this should also help

http://blog.cylewitruk.com/2010/09/wpf-combobox-and-databinding-datacontext-itemssource-displaymemberpath-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedvaluepath/

//model

```
public class Cars
{
    public int CarID {get;set}
    public int CarName {get;set}
    // Foreign key
    public int EngineMakerID { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual EngineMakers  EngineMakers  { get; set; }
}
public class EngineMakers
{
    public int EngineMakerID {get;set}
    public int EngineMakerName {get;set}
    // Navigation properties
    public virtual List<EngineMakers> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

// ViewModel

```
  public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
    {

         public ObservableCollection<Cars>  Cars { get; private set; }
         public Cars SelectedSourceCars { get; set; }
    }
```

//Binding

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Cars, Mode=OneWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSourceCars}" />
```

Comment: Great answer but Kushi don't forget to instanciate your ViewModel